# Playframework jpa pagination skips every second page

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, playframework

I'm running playframework 1.2.4 with jpa and mysql.

i have a job that retrieves the first 20 Activities from the DB, sets the status to active to stop other job instances executing them, executes the acitivity then gets the next page of Activities and repeats until all activities are complete. However it seems to be skipping every second page, or 20 records where my page size is 20. My logic is as follows.

```
long total = Activity.count(q, params);
int page = 1;
int pageSize = 20;

int pages = ...

while (page <= pages) {

JPAPlugin.startTx(false);
Collection<Activity> activities = Activity.find(query, params).fetch(page, pageSize);

for (Activity activity : activities) {
    activity.status = ActivityStatus.ACTIVE;
    activity.save();
}
JPAPlugin.closeTx(false);

JPAPlugin.startTx(false);
for (Activity activity : activities) 
    longProcessActivityInAnotherTransaction(activity);
JPAPlugin.closeTx(false);

page++;
}
```

However in the database, i see records 1-20 with status ACTIVE, 21-40 without status ACTIVE, 61-80 with status ACTIVE and so on.

it seems to be something to do with the transactions. if i comment out all the transaction start/close code within the while loop, and just print out the ids of the activities selected, i can see that all activities are correctly selected.

also if i run in debug mode and pause execution mid loop, and run the generated query directly against the mysql database, i see the same behaviour as in the code. when the loop isnt executing, the sql queries perform as expected.

my connection string is:

mysql://root:pass@localhost/dbname

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem came down to how i was changing the Activity during the paging query. I selected a page of the first 20 that have a status of PENDING. then during that page, i would set the status of those 20 to FINISHED. then i would get the second page of 20 PENDING. this subsequent query obvioulsy would ignore the first 20 that i'd set to FINISHED (id 1-20) and treat Activities with id 21-40 as page 1, and would thus select page 2, which was Activites with id 41-60.

So the fix was to not using paging as such, but just limit the results to the first 20 (page size) each time and loop this query while page <= pages